# Google Analytics: How to keep word after # in URL? ex: /brands#my-brandname

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having an issue where the Active Pages section only shows the path and not the term that appears after the `#` (ex: `www.mysite.com/brands#my-brandname` shows up as `www.mysite.com/brands`). Is there a setting in the javascript for GA to log the `#` and everything after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to include the hash portion in your pageviews like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);
```

if you are using classic GA, or like this if you are using Universal Analytics:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});
```

Comment: If I made this change, would I see it instantly in the Real Time dashboard?

Comment: Yes, you should, but only if everything else is working correctly. :)